# Crear diccionario a partir de 2 listas donde las claves están duplicadas

Tags: python, lista, diccionarios, spyder

En python tengo 2 listas, donde a partir de estas 2 listas me gustaría crear un diccionario:

```
claves =[1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,4,3,2]
valores=[5,4,2,1,7,8,7,6,5,6,8,7]
```

Lo que me gustaría conseguir es un diccionario donde para la clave 1 tuviese los valores 5,4,2. Es decir, que me fuese detectando las claves y añadiendo a esa clave los valores. Lo que no se implementar es cómo hacer un bucle para que me detecte que para la clave 1 son los valores 5,4,2 y me vaya así sucesivamente. Ya que al tener claves duplicadas es donde estoy fallando.

¿Alguien tiene idea de como realizarlo?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar un diccionario y agregar los elementos a él usando un bucle for y la función dict.setdefault() para agregar valores a las claves.

```
claves = [1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,4,3,2]
valores = [5,4,2,1,7,8,7,6,5,6,8,7]

diccionario = {}

for clave, valor in zip(claves, valores):
  diccionario.setdefault(clave, []).append(valor)

print(diccionario)
```

Esto produce la siguiente salida:

```
{1: [5, 4, 2], 2: [1, 7], 3: [7, 6], 4: [8, 5], 5: [7], 6: [8]}
```

Comment: "mediante el uso del operador +=." esto donde esta en tu codigo?

Comment: Relacionado [cheatGPT (chatGPT) nos ha alcanzado en SOes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5450/cheatgpt-chatgpt-nos-ha-alcanzado-en-soes)

Comment: Muchas gracias @Jr_root por la respuesta, tenía una base de datos de millones de registros y pude crear de esta manera un diccionario con sus respectivas claves y valores de forma correcta.

Comment: @MauricioContreras que estas insinuando, hay algún boot en la sala? Yo nuevo nuevo no soy, soy algo nuevo con algunas tecnologías en las que voy un poco perdido, de ahí mi pregunta

Comment: @pint34, no. No es un bot. Hay usuarios que están usando las capacidades de chatGPT para publicar respuestas como si fuesen propias.

Answer (score 1):

Acá les muestro una forma efectiva de ganarse votos negativos, mi respuesta no es acorde a lo que se pide, más explícitamente, @pint34 pide un **map**, y yo ofrezco un array, pero creo que a pesar de eso, es un buen ejercicio mental, que puede servir a alguien.

```
   int claves[] = { 1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,4,3,2 };
   int valores[] = { 5,4,2,1,7,8,7,6,5,6,8,7 };

   int[][] transformar(  ) {
      int sale[][] = new int[ 7 ][ 3 ];
      int aux[] = new int[ 7 ];
      for( int i = 0; i < valores.length; i++ ) {
         int indice = claves[ i ] -1;
         int indice2 = aux[ indice ];
         sale[ indice ] [ indice2 ] = valores[ i ];
         aux[ indice ] ++;
      }
      return sale;
   }
```

Esta es la versión **encriptada**, más difícil de leer, pero más corta.

```
   int[][] transformacion(  ) {
      int sale[][] = new int[ 7 ][ 3 ];
      int aux[] = new int[ 7 ];
      for( int i = 0; i < valores.length; i++ ) {
         sale[ claves[ i ] -1 ] [ aux[ claves[ i ] -1 ] ] = valores[ i ];
         aux[ claves[ i ] -1 ] ++;
      }
      return sale;
   }
```

Lo malo de este enfoque, es que es necesario saber de antemano, el tamaño del array de salida, y que por defecto, las posiciones no instanciadas tendrán valor **0**.